# tcl query for string pattern matching

Tags: php, unix, tcl

I have a Tcl variable with the following contents:

```
m_hscaclbmbmmer_v11_2 
m_letmmcbterbox_v1_2 
m_osbbbbcmd_v16_0 v_proc_ss_v1_0 
m_rmgbbb2cycrcb_v17_4
m_nscalbbbcer_v8_2
m_smpte2mbbc022_m12_rx_v2_3
m_smpte2m02cm2_12_tx_v2_2
m_smpte20m2mcm2_56_rx_v5_4
m_smpte202m2_c56_tx_v4_0 
m_smpbbbte_sdbbci_v3_0
m_smpte_uhdmsdic_v1_2
m_tmmmc_v6_4 
m_tpmmmg_v17_1
m_vcresamcpler_v1_2
m_vid_mminc_axi4s_v14_1
m_voip_femcc_rx_v11_3
m_voip_fmbmecc_tx_v1_2
m_vscalebcr_v1_4
m_ycrcb2bncrgb_v7_4
mid_phy_cnmcbmbontroller_v2_2
mibmmbbo_v3_4
miterbcbmbi_v9_4
madc_wicbmbz_v3_4
mambmbuic_v12_2  mvxfftc_v9_4
```

The last name, `mvxfftc_v9_4`, needs to be changed into   `microsemi.com:ip:mvxfft:9.4`, the same needs to be done to all names. How do I do that?

Comment: hi all i need convert each core name , as in last two line and store them in a single variable what i am thinking is to concatenation microsemi.com and then do string pattern matiching with changing verison to unserscore to .

Comment: You want to change all occurrences of `mvxfftc_v9_4`?

Comment: hi dinesh , my question i want change each core , for example

Comment: m_hscaclbmbmmer_v1_2 into    microsemi.com:ip: m_hscaclbmbmmer:1.4 in simliar fashion i need to change all core into similar fashion i hope u got it ,if not please let me know

Comment: I tried to clean up your question to be legible. I suppose the **strong text** part shouldn't be there, and that the occurrences of names on the same line should be on different lines, please edit to reflect your intents.

Comment: i am sorry peter, can u let know  me what is stron text part please ?

Comment: Look in the middle of the column, after `m_tmmmc_v6_4`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is slightly under-specified, but I'm assuming that you are taking each name like this (marking the parts to be extracted):

```
mvxfftc_v9_4
^^^^^^   ^ ^
```

and transforming that to (marking the parts inserted):

```
microsemi.com:ip:mvxfft:9.4
                 ^^^^^^ ^ ^
```

That's not too hard with `regsub`, and since we're changing a well-formed word to a well-formed word, we can probably just use it directly on the variable as string processing without needing to map it over the list explicitly:

```
set changed [regsub -all {\y(\w+)\w_v(\d+)_(\d+)\y} $original {microsemi.com:ip:\1:\2.\3}]
# \y is a beginning-or-end-of-word anchor
# \w means any alphanumeric-or-underscore
# \d means any digit
# \1, \2 and \3 are substituted by the parenthesised matches
```

There's a limit to the complexity of mappings that you can do this way, but maybe this will be enough.

Comment: And once again I'm caught choosing the messier way in the "interest" of simpler presentation. Some day I'll learn. However, I believe excluding the last character before the underscore-v-digit part was a typo: the whole name part should be preserved.

Comment: @PeterLewerin It really depends on the details. I could quite easily believe that using `lmap` is better in many real scenarios where things are a bit more complicated; `regsub` can only really do “pick things out of a template and place them into a different template” though it can do that quite well.

Comment: hi donal , thanks for reply i need more matching in the exp because my list got updated with more core name like m_viteber_v12_3 like some core are added

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try (assuming your list of names is in `name`):

```
foreach name $names {
    puts microsemi.com:ip:[regsub {_v(\d)_(\d)$} $name {:\1.\2}]
}
```

It's not pretty, but it does what you seem to be saying that you want done.

If you want a list instead of a printout, you could use this (Tcl 8.6 or later, leaves result in `result`):

```
set result [lmap name $names {
    lindex microsemi.com:ip:[regsub {_v(\d)_(\d)$} $name {:\1.\2}]
}]
```

or this (most versions):

```
set result {}
foreach name $names {
    lappend result microsemi.com:ip:[regsub {_v(\d)_(\d)$} $name {:\1.\2}]
}
```

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

On regular expression writing:

- http://tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl20.html (and the two following)
- [http://wiki.tcl.tk/_//search?submit=Search&S=regular+expression&*charset*=UTF-8](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_//search?submit=Search&S=regular+expression&_charset_=UTF-8)

There are also a few sites dedicated to regular expressions for various programming languages: a Google search should help you.

Comment: hi peter , i will remove strong text type from my question , thanks for code ,what i ubderstood from answer is this :

Comment: ur appending the microsemi.com:ip: til there i am clear , but wht i understood is that ur hardcoding version  name but it has to  also patter matching which v9_4 it has has to changed into  :9.4

Comment: hi i am having cores aslo like m_rmgbbb2cycrcb_v13_4  added recently, then the expression gets changed right

Comment: @user864752: yes, if a number can have more than one digit you match it with `\d+` instead of `\d`.

Comment: thanks peter ,i am new to tcl and this pattern matching is most confusing ...how learn this patttern  matching in tcl is there any learning website please let me know

Comment: @user864752: I've added a couple of links. Regular expressions are hard, though, and the only real way to get to grok them is by using them and experimenting a lot. I.e. don't expect to learn how to do it just by reading a tutorial.

Comment: i haven written this code  when i am trying to run i am getting -1 why set s1 "sekhar"
set s2 "sekhar"
puts [string compare s1 s2]

Comment: @user864752: because the string "s1" comes before "s2". You need dollar signs to get the values.